# guzzle NULL response lumen php oauth2

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, guzzle, lumen

I have used [this](http://esbenp.github.io/2015/05/26/lumen-web-api-oauth-2-authentication/) for lumen oauth2.0.

I followed all steps.
But I got an error. I got NULL response from guzzle. Please check code in proxy.php below.

```
namespace App\Auth;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
class Proxy {
public function attemptLogin($credentials)
{
    return $this->proxy('password', $credentials);
}
public function attemptRefresh()
{
    $crypt = app()->make('encrypter');
    $request = app()->make('request');
    return $this->proxy('refresh_token', [
        'refresh_token' => $crypt->decrypt($request->cookie('refreshToken'))
    ]);
}
private function proxy($grantType, array $data = [])
{
    try {
        $config = app()->make('config');
        $data = array_merge([
            'client_id'     => $config->get('secrets.client_id'),
            'client_secret' => $config->get('secrets.client_secret'),
            'grant_type'    => $grantType
        ], $data);
        $client = new Client();
        $guzzleResponse = $client->post(sprintf('%s/oauth/access-token', $config->get('app.url')), [
            'form_params' => $data
        ]);
    } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        $guzzleResponse = $e->getResponse();
    }
    $response = json_decode($guzzleResponse->getBody());
    if (property_exists($response, "access_token")) {
        $cookie = app()->make('cookie');
        $crypt  = app()->make('encrypter');
        $encryptedToken = $crypt->encrypt($response->refresh_token);
        // Set the refresh token as an encrypted HttpOnly cookie
        $cookie->queue('refreshToken',
            $encryptedToken,
            604800, // expiration, should be moved to a config file
            null,
            null,
            false,
            true // HttpOnly
        );
        $response = [
            'accessToken'            => $response->access_token,
            'accessTokenExpiration'  => $response->expires_in
        ];
    }
    $response = response()->json($response);
    $response->setStatusCode($guzzleResponse->getStatusCode());
    $headers = $guzzleResponse->getHeaders();
    foreach($headers as $headerType => $headerValue) {
        $response->header($headerType, $headerValue);
    }
    return $response;
}
}
```

In above code guzzle post request give me NULL response. Check '$response' from proxy function.

I have searched for it. 
Author of this article mentioned that

1. Make sure that memcached is installed or not.
2. Check url in lumen/config/app.php

   ```
   return [
     'url' => 'http://localhost/lumen/lumen/public/',
     'key' => 'U<CdJu~T&.g/kR-NX55h]HfB+bb,b7Y*',
     'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'
    ];
   ```
3. Check .env file and change AUTH_MODEL=App\Auth\User

   ```
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_KEY=12asgvgjuiklp008765434d

    APP_LOCALE=en
    APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en

    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=lumen
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=

    AUTH_MODEL=App\Auth\User

    CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
    SESSION_DRIVER=memcached
    QUEUE_DRIVER=database

    # MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    # MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
    # MAIL_PORT=2525
    # MAIL_USERNAME=null
    # MAIL_PASSWORD=null
    # MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
    # MAIL_FROM_NAME=null

    # FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
    # FILESYSTEM_CLOUD=s3

    # S3_KEY=null
    # S3_SECRET=null
    # S3_REGION=null
    # S3_BUCKET=null

    # RACKSPACE_USERNAME=null
    # RACKSPACE_KEY=null
    # RACKSPACE_CONTAINER=null
    # RACKSPACE_REGION=null
   ```

everything has been done. Still I'm getting an error.

Comment: I think it will work on virtual host, but still you can try SESSION_DRIVER=cookie instead of SESSION_DRIVER=memcached in .env file

Answer (score 2):

Sometime guzzle does not work with port

If your server was running on http://localhost:8080
just removed port 8080 and run it on http://localhost
and it will start working.